# Highcharts possible to push xAxis categories through for-loop?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, categories

I have a highchart which I hard-coded the xAxis categories as shown. 
filteredDatas.xAxis is an array which contains date
filteredDatas.xAxisTime holds 24 values for 24 hours a day.

```
xAxis: {                
            categories: [{
                name: filteredDatas.xAxis[0],
                categories: filteredDatas.xAxisTime
            }, {
                name: filteredDatas.xAxis[1],
                categories: filteredDatas.xAxisTime
            }, {
                name: filteredDatas.xAxis[2],
                categories: filteredDatas.xAxisTime
            }, {
                name: filteredDatas.xAxis[3],
                categories: filteredDatas.xAxisTime
            }, {
                name: filteredDatas.xAxis[4],
                categories: filteredDatas.xAxisTime
            }, {
                name: filteredDatas.xAxis[5],
                categories: filteredDatas.xAxisTime
            }, {
                name: filteredDatas.xAxis[6],
                categories: filteredDatas.xAxisTime
            }],
},
```

[image: The highchart then looks like this]

However, If I select other date ranges more than 7 days, the xaxis label becomes like this.

[image]

I figured out that I should dynamically push the name and categories in by using a for-loop and an accumulator. But I couldnt find how the syntax should be written. I need to loop for N times to push in N times of filteredDatas.xAxis and filteredDatas.xAxisTime. This might be stupidly easy to achieve, Im still a beginner in highcharts. Any help please?

Comment: Are you trying to use groupedCategories plugin? Have you included it correctly? Also, any chance to create jsFiddle example with that issue?

Comment: If you're working with time series data, it makes much more sense to use a 'datetime' x axis type, and will eliminate this problem altogether. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.type |

Comment: @jlbriggs Is it possible for me to group the axis label using datetime type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this can help you

```
 xAxis: {
        categories: function(){
            var data;
            for(var i=0;i<filteredDatas.xAxis.length;i++){
                data.push({
                    name: filteredDatas.xAxis[i],
                    categories: filteredDatas.xAxisTime
             })
            };
            return data;
        }
    },
```

or you can set a N variable to define the number of iterations the for loop will do

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I followed what you said. Came out error message 'unexpected token u'. I googled about it and found out that there might be some problem with the web essentials extension. I cant find the folder anywhere, so I am figuring out what the problem is.

Comment: Edited the location of the push data javascript and it worked! Thanks a lot for your idea! Edited your answer, marked as correct and +1 for the help!

Comment: If you want to post your own complete solution, go ahead and post it as a separate answer. :) Go ahead and keep this answer accepted if it helped.